# Find folders who have at least two files over 100 MB?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, files

How can I only list folders who have at least two files over 100 MB in them?

Comment: You were probably downvoted because your question sounds like homework with little effort from your side. This requires a shell script. Depending on where those folders reside, you can use `find START -t d` to list all folders in the filesystem subtree whose top is START, or use `ls -F` to list all subfolders in the current folder. Then, for each of those folders, list the files it contains and count those whose size is over 100MB. `ls -l` is not recommended to list the files; perhaps something like `stat -c %s *` would be better.

Comment: @berndbausch ya, as I clicked Post I thought folks would think this is a homework question and not help. Thanks for your help. I simply have old/duplicate videos files in 5000+ folders that weren't removed properly. I had part of the puzzle with the command `find ./ -type f -size +100M` but realized there's no way I can sift through 5000+ lines of output to identity the folders in question

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to show what exactly you are trying to do and what you have tried to resolve it - i.e. moving your comment into the actual question itself. In general in SE sites providing exact information in the question helps you to get a better answer faster, and when the issue gets resolved it helps others with similar problem finding the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### With `find` and `awk` :

List all files > 100M

```
$ find . -type f -size +100M
./bar/ok
./foo/okp
./foo/ok
```

##### Now filter with `awk`:

```
$ find . -type f -size +100M -exec dirname {} + |
    awk '{dir[$0]++}END{for (i in dir) if (dir[i] >= 2) print i}'
./foo
```

It output only dirs with at least two files with > 100M, as requested.

If your implementation of `dirname` don't support multiple dirs at once, use `{} \;` instead with `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU tools, you could print the directories (`%h`) of all files greater than 100MiB and print all duplicate results once with `uniq -d`.
To process directory names containing newlines, we use the NUL character (`\0` and option `-z`) as line terminator and convert it to the newline character in the last step.

```
find . -type f -size +100M -printf '%h\0' | uniq -dz | tr '\0' '\n'
```

To prefix each result with the number of matches (>=2) found, add `-c` to `uniq`:

```
find . -type f -size +100M -printf '%h\0' | uniq -cdz | tr '\0' '\n'
```